# How To Make Font Awesome Elements Have Discernable Names?

Tags: font-awesome, lighthouse

Bonjour,

Trying to solve the audit point of discernable names of font awesome icons/elements using [Lighthouse](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/) I dont't know how answer to this challenge : How To Make Font Awesome Elements Have Discernable Names ?

The [actual result in Lighthouse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jt4kd.jpg) ask for "Elements Have Discernable Names"

here is the basic code

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/blablabla"><i class="fa fa-twitter black"></i></a>
```

Best regards

J.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the aria-label property to pass the audit.

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/blablabla" aria-label="twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter black"></i></a>
```

More information about aria-label can be found at https://dev.opera.com/articles/ux-accessibility-aria-label/#accessible-name-calculation

Comment: Nice article, thanks a lot - it works ! -have a greath sunday !